# Find a value from the json string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

This is my json string :

```
{"loginAccounts": [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "accountId": "123456",
        "baseUrl": "https://abc.defghi.com/test/t12/remark/123456",
        "isDefault": "true",
        "userName": "Ceilina James",
        "userId": "7c5bat57-850a-5c93-39eb-2015ai9o8822",
        "email": "abc@test.com",
        "siteDescription": ""
    }
]}
```

I need "baseUrl" value. How to find it in the C# ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a JSON serializer such as the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class to deserialize this JSON string to a C# class and then extract the required value. For example you could have the following model:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public LoginAccount[] LoginAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class LoginAccount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string IsDefault { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
string json = "... your JSON string comes here ...";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = ...
var model = (SomeModel)serializer.Deserialize(json);
foreach (var account in model.LoginAccounts)
{
    string baseUrl = account.BaseUrl;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
foreach (var acc in JObject.Parse(json)["loginAccounts"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(acc["baseUrl"]);
}
```